# Is there model selection score for GEE models besides the scale?

Tags: statsmodels

I need to compare different repeated measure or random effect models whose parameters have been inferred with GEE.

However, there is no model-selection variable besides the scale. 
Has anyone implemented the AIC alternative for GEE proposed by Pan?

http://50.28.42.145/faculty/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/rr2000-013.pdf

Other options for model are welcome